# Adding rows to mysql - get sorted randomly - want them on top

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have kind of a "problem" that I do not know how it happened. If I add rows to my table via php it just adds them randomly somewhere. But I want them to be added on top. Instead it justs add them all over the table.

```
 $name = ($_GET["name"]);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_Table VALUES('$name')";

 $number = ($_GET["number"]);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_Table VALUES('$number')";

 $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die (mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO $DB_Table (Name,number)
 VALUES ('$name','$m_yolo')");



 $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());


        mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "faild";
}// end else
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as row ordering in a relational table. If you want them ordered, you need to use an `ORDER BY` clause. You can add a `TIMESTAMP` column, which you can sort on when you select your data: [11.3.1. The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create another table but add an ID auto-increment column in it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Then you can insert new rows like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_Table (id, name,number) VALUES ('', '$name', '$number')";
```

Your new entries will be sorted by id then. You can order them in you select query with:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'name', 'number' FROM `table` ORDER BY 'id' DESC";
```

One remark about your code though: it is not safe to directly use the values from $_GET as you do at the beginning of your code. Try using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for example.